# Efficiently populate a look-up table for a function over a range of arguments

Tags: optimization, numerical-algorithms

I am minimizing a scalar function $f$ which takes a $n$-dimensional vector input and outputs a scalar value.  I have code that given an input $x$ will compute the output of $f(x)$ (a scalar), its Jacobian (a $n$-dim vector), and its Hessian (a $n \times n$ matrix).  In my application, $n \approx 10$.  Unfortunately, evaluating the function $f$ takes too long for many points. I'd like to build a surrogate model $\hat{f}$ instead that I can use for minimization.

I've been thinking of a scheme based on precomputing $f$ at a regularly spaced grid of inputs, and then $\hat{f}(x)$ would perform linear interpolation based on the grid points nearest to $x$.  However, this requires regular sampling and might be inaccurate due to the use of linear interpolation.

I'm hoping there is a more intelligent method for this? Perhaps with automatic refinement of inputs sampled or a more sophisticated interpolation scheme?

Technically, the output contains the Jacobian and Hessian but I need those with decent fidelity, so I would either need a higher order representation of the scalar function (with added sampling frequency) or I need to approximate the Jacobian and Hessian too.

Comment: Can you check whether my edit captures what you're trying to achieve, and if not, [edit] further?  Coding questions, Python-specific questions, and requests for tools/software packages/products are off-topic here, but asking for algorithms or methods are on-topic.

Comment: I suspect that this is not answerable without knowing anything about your function $f$.  The choice of method will probably depend on what particular function you have in mind; what can you tell us about its properties and its definition?